# Position absolute not working in IE?

Tags: jquery, css

What's supposed to happen: Using jquery when the user scrolls past a certain point, a class is added to a div which fixes it in place. Since I don't know what the problem is, although I think it may be that the fixed div is inside an absolute positioned div, I uploaded the page to the internets so you can look at all of the code. The page works fine in chrome and firefox, just not IE.
http://jakespp.co.cc/backtotop/
Thanks

Comment: It does work nice in chrome, but you set it to not even show in IE so how are we supposed to see whats going wrong? silly :p

Comment: forgot about that, i'll change the htaccess file as soon as :P

Comment: I do, however, completely agree with you ha.

Comment: should be working now :D, i spend too much time optimising my site for ie...

Comment: IE is notorious for not implimenting CSS correctly (or even reasonably). Always remember: As competence approaches zero the likelyhood of being hired by Microsoft approaches infinity (at least for the IE dev team).

Comment: @dwb yes, yes. But `position: absolute` is not known to give problems in any browser.

Comment: Using IE's developer tools and debugger (as best I can it confuses me), as far as I can tell the "fixed" class isn't getting added.  I don't think that .scrolltop() is working right.  If it keeps returning 0 than the class will not be added and it will stay at the top of the page instead of moving.  I can't figure much more out though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the DOCTYPE declaration (eg.) to the top of the HTML document to get it to work. IE quirks!!

PS. I think it might be the position:fixed that is not working in IE